# How to integrate an image gallery made with Roundabout with Fancybox?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I am trying to create a compact image gallery using the [Roundabout](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/) plugin.

The carousel should rotate the thumbnails and, only for the image currently on focus, open the larger image in a [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) popup when clicked.

This is how the markup looks like:

```
<ul class="image-gallery">
    <li id="img-1"><a href="images/picture1.jpg"><img src="images/th2_picture1.jpg" alt="picture 1" /></a></li>
    <li id="img-2"><a href="images/picture2.jpg"><img src="images/th2_picture2.jpg" alt="picture 2" /></a></li>
    <li id="img-3"><a href="images/picture3.jpg"><img src="images/th2_picture3.jpg" alt="picture 3" /></a></li>
    <li id="img-4"><a href="images/picture4.jpg"><img src="images/th2_picture4.jpg" alt="picture 4" /></a></li>
    <li id="img-5"><a href="images/picture5.jpg"><img src="images/th2_picture5.jpg" alt="picture 5" /></a></li>
    <li id="img-6"><a href="images/picture6.jpg"><img src="images/th2_picture6.jpg" alt="picture 6" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

The problem is, if I try to activate both Roundabout and Fancybox on the images, clicking on them will trigger both the rotation and the popup, no matter on which image I clicked on. The popup, instead, should only be active for the image currently in focus.
I cannot unbind the click event on thumbnails, because this would disable the rotation too..
This is a [link to an example page](http://www.allforweb.info/musei/musei/4_Museo%20Civico%20Amedeo%20Lia/) (the gallery is at the bottom of the page).

**EDIT:**
Here's the jQuery that runs on page load:

```
$(function() {
    $('ul.image-gallery').roundabout({
        duration: 1200
    });
    $('ul.image-gallery a').fancybox();
});
```

Comment: how are you mapping fancybox? can you show that code?

Comment: @Naren sorry, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "mapping"..

Comment: asked for the same code which you have added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, after inspecting the page you have mentioned, the focus image have roundabout-in-focus class so following may resolve this issue. try it

```
$(function() {
    $('ul.image-gallery').roundabout({
        duration: 1200
    });
    //$('ul.image-gallery .roundabout-in-focus a').fancybox();
});
```

**Edit:** 
 try to map the click event of focused image link and open fancybox manually for link url. Also remove fancybox mapping in above function. (I've commented it in code)

```
$('ul.image-gallery .roundabout-in-focus a').live('click',function(event){
event.preventDefault();
$.fancybox({'href':$(this).attr('href')});
})
```

Comment: sorry, I already tried that approach, but the problem is, fancybox gets activated only on the element that is in-focus **when the page loads**, when you rotate the carousel fancybox does not dynamically "move" to the element currently in focus.

Comment: then you can try to map the click event of focused image link and can open the fancy box manually. see edit section

Comment: that works nice! thanks!
here's the final result: [link](http://www.allforweb.info/musei/index.php)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the options you're

```
$('ul.image-gallery').find('li').focus(function() {
        $(this).find('a').fancybox.cancel();
    }
});
```

This assumes that you are using roundabout on the ul, and fancybox on the anchor tags inside of them.  When the roundabout gives focus to an li, it cancels the fancybox that will do the same thing.

Comment: Actually, fancybox should be active for the element currently in focus, from what I understand you are disabling it instead..  
Moreover, I get an error saying that `cancel` is not recognised as a function: `$(this).find("a").fancybox.cancel is not a function`