# Is it possible to disable/re-enable fancybox only on specific elements?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I need to turn off/on fancybox on the elements of a list according to their focus status.
I cannot bind/unbind the click event completely, because there are other functions listening for the same event.
So, I need to know if fancybox provides a way of doing so.
If not, any alternatives to fancybox that meet this requirement would be appreciated as well.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, none of the solutions proposed was the one I was looking for...
The correct answer was provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6057686/how-to-integrate-an-image-gallery-made-with-roundabout-with-fancybox) by @Naren Sisodiya, who suggested using the `live()` method (which at the time hadn't been surpassed yet by the new `on` method).
I admit that the question could have been asked in a better form.. Sorry everyone..
Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Why don't you simply play with the classes of your elements using addClass and removeClass?  Then only when they have this class the fancybox will be triggered.

K

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$('#element').removeClass('fancybox');
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

fancybox have a binded click events, they have a proxy-name - fb-start, you can unbind handler.

It works for me,

```
$("#your-element").fancybox(); //fancybox is binded click.fb-start on #your-element

$( "#your-element" ).unbind('click.fb-start');  //click is unbinded
```

for this you must have a jquery library is loaded